# solving a recursion related to inverse preferential attachment in growing trees

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, recursion, trees

We consider a growing tree.  Let $f(i,N)$ be the expected number of nodes of degree $i$ after $N$ nodes were attached to the tree.

Assume that nodes are degree-averse, i.e., they attach to nodes with probability inversely proportional to degrees.

Then,

\begin{align}
f(1,N+1)&=\frac{f(1,N)}{\sum f(j,N)/j } f(1,N) + \left(1-\frac{f(1,N)}{\sum f(j,N)/j } \right)(f(1,N)+1) \\
f(i,N+1)&=\frac{f(i,N)/i}{\sum f(j,N)/j} (f(i,N)-1)   +\frac{f(i-1,N)/(i-1)}{\sum f(j,N)/j} (f(i,N)+1)   +\left(1-\frac{f(i,N)/i}{\sum f(j,N)/j} - \frac{f(i-1,N)/(i-1)}{\sum f(j,N)/j}  \right)f(i,N) \\
\end{align}
i.e.,
\begin{align}
f(1,N+1)&=\left(1-\frac{1}{\sum f(j,N)/j } \right)f(1,N)+1 \\
f(i,N+1)&=\left(1-\frac{1/i}{\sum f(j,N)/j } \right) {f(i,N)}    +\frac{f(i-1,N)/(i-1)}{\sum f(j,N)/j}    \\
\end{align}

We also have
\begin{align}
f(1,2)&=2 \\
f(i,N)&=0, \textrm{ for }  N\leq i
\end{align}

Letting $g(i,N)=f(i,N)/i$,

\begin{align}
g(1,N+1)&=\left(1-\frac{1}{\sum g(j,N) } \right)g(1,N)+1 \\
 g(i,N+1)&=\left(1-\frac{1/i}{\sum g(j,N) } \right) { g(i,N)}    +\frac{g(i-1,N)}{i \sum g(j,N)}    \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
g(1,2)&=2 \\
g(i,N)&=0, \textrm{ for }  N\leq i
\end{align}

How to solve the above recursion, for $i=2, 3, \ldots, N$?

PS: this question is inspired by Distribution of nodes of a tree by degree
Na, Hwa Sung; Rapoport, Anatol
1970 https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/handle/2027.42/32846

Also, it seems that the average node quality, $(1/N)\sum f(j,N)/j = \sum g(j,N)/N$, converges to an asymptotic value. Which value is this? Here I'm assuming that the quality of a node is inversely proportional to its degree.

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to define $g(i, N) = \frac 1if(i,N)$ and rewrite it all in terms of $g$ instead of $f$.